# Azure websites - multiple standard instances, possible?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

It appears to me that when you create multiple Standard (reserved) websites in Azure, they all get grouped together in 1 Standard VM instance. Is this by design? If so, does anyone know of a way to have multiple Standard VMs, each with their own group of websites, each able to scale independently of each other? I imagine I could accomplish this by creating another subscription and adding a Standard website instance to that, but I don't want to do that before I make sure that that is the one and only way to go. Any thoughts out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible at the moment. You get one server farm per webspace for now.

You can get that if you don't care about the geographic location though. Basically every geographic location will get a new webspace, but I am guessing you probably care. Also even then you can get only up to 6 server farms for the 6 geolocations that Azure Websites is available on.